# Callback of a load function jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback, load, jquery-callback

I want to be able to do the callback of the `.load()` function when an element has been created - an image element. The code works by loading a new image element by this code:

```
$('<img />').load(function()
{
    var img = this;
    $('.block-wrap img').fadeOut('slow', function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith(img);
    });
}).attr('src', loadurl);
```

But I want to be able to continue when the image has been loaded and replaced. This is how I need it to work:

```
$('<img />').load(function()
{
    var img = this;
    $('.block-wrap img').fadeOut('slow', function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith(img);
    });
}).attr('src', loadurl);

$('.block-wrap input.imageheight').val($('.block-wrap img').height());
$('.block-wrap input.imagewidth').val($('.block-wrap img').width());
```

It returns the first image height (not the image that has been replaced which is a loading spinner image), so I need it to be able to retrieve the image height and width when it has fully loaded into the DOM. Too bad `.replaceWith()` does not have a callback method, but I cannot use a callback function on the `.load()` since it will not work due to it's a function that has been passed through the `.load()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this but could you not add a load event to the end of replaceWith? I.E:

```
$(this).replaceWith(img).load(function(){

   $('.block-wrap input.imageheight').val($('.block-wrap img').height());
   $('.block-wrap input.imagewidth').val($('.block-wrap img').width());

});
```

Comment: Hmmm. It's plausible, it always returned `0` for each values, so I wrapped them with a `setTimeout()` of 100ms, which returned the image dimensions. Still not sure if there is a much better solution than this.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning the wrong image dimensions, because `$('.block-wrap img').height()` and `$('.block-wrap img').width()` are being called *before* `.load()` finishes.

You can put those two lines inside the `load` callback (after the `.replaceWith`), so that they refer to the correct image.

```
$('<img />').load(function()
{
    var img = this;
    $('.block-wrap img').fadeOut('slow', function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith(img);
        $('.block-wrap input.imageheight').val($('.block-wrap img').height());
        $('.block-wrap input.imagewidth').val($('.block-wrap img').width());
    });
}).attr('src', loadurl);
```